# Entity Relationship User and Contacts

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship

I am trying to create database where users has contacts. I designed the tables below and I am confused about the part  how the relationship should be because it looks like it should be one to many , but its also many to many relationship.

In database each user has to have contacts table that contacts are other user in database. But contacts has to belong the each user.

Whats the relationship in this case?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's the relationship in this case?

Many to Many.

In your Contacts table, you have an owner_id and a contact_id.  You could just as easily call these columns user_1_id and user_2_id.

Using your column names, a contact_id can have many owner_id's, and an owner_id can have many contact_id's.

The clustering (primary) index on the Contacts table is (owner_id, contact_id).  You also need to define one unique index on the Contacts table, (contact_id, owner_id).

Answer (score 1):

A contact is a person, and so is a user (and a company is a legal person).

A person can play the role of a user, or not.

A person can have a relationship with another person, over a period of time.

An example party_relationship.type would be "contact of"

[image]